# Python Conda terminal not responce

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I run my Python code with using tensorflow. I do this many times before. But now, after some time console just stops doing anything. I use anaconda environment.

The memory is still busy, but processor does nothing else. This happen in random iteration of loop, sometimes at 5 iteration, sometimes 2000. I don’t have asynchronous code. I'm just learning a neural network. And before this code worked correctly many times. I changed only data preparation and this stage goes without problems. So I think that the matter is something else.

OS: Windows 10

UPD 1: I can’t even interrupt the code at this moment (with CTRL+C)

What could it be?

Comment: We have practically no information to work with.

Comment: no errors are shown to me. I was hoping that this is an exclusively conda problem and that someone had it.